# Unexpected results for high order function

Tags: perl

I have a higher order function that maps even position values in an array:

```
sub map_even(&@) {
    my $block = shift;
    my @res;
    for $i (0..$#_) {
        push @res, $i%2 ? $_[$i] : &$block($_[$i]);
     }
    @res;
}
print map_even {$_*$_} 1,2,3,4;
```

I am expecting the output to be `14316`, but the actual output is

```
0204
```

Why does this happen and how can I fix this? And is there any improvement can be done to the code?

Comment: Please *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the start of *every* Perl program you write, especially if you are asking for help with it. The message `Use of uninitialized value $_ in multiplication (*)` would have given you a big hint to the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your anonymous function you have to access first input argument via `$_[0]` (hint: `@_` array).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub map_even(&@) {
    my $block = shift;
    my @res;
    for my $i (0..$#_) {
        push @res, $i%2 ? $block->($_[$i]) : $_[$i];
     }
    @res;
}
print join ",", map_even {$_[0]*$_[0]} 1,2,3,4;
```

output

```
1,4,3,16
```

Using `$_`,

```
sub map_even(&@) {
    my $block = shift;
    my @res;
    for my $i (0..$#_) {
        push @res, $i%2 ? $block->() : $_ for $_[$i];
        # or
        # local $_ = $_[$i];
        # push @res, $i%2 ? $block->() : $_;
     }
    @res;
}
print join ",", map_even {$_*$_} 1,2,3,4;
```

Comment: The $_[0] is not very intuitive... How can I use just $_?

Answer (score 3):

In your `map_even` block, you use the special `$_`  variable. However, you have to set it inside your loop:

```
local $_ = $_[$i];
... $block->();
```

The `$_` is a global variable and can be temporarily overridden with the `local` operator. The `$_` has nothing to do with subroutine arguments.

---

About aliasing: Perls `for`, `map` and `grep` mostly alias `$_` to the current element as a performance hack, not because this behavior would be particularly desirable. In order to perform an alias, you should localize the whole `*_` typeglob which contains the `$_` variable and then assign a scalar reference of the alias target to the glob:

```
local *_ = \$_[$i];
```

Comment: @texasbruce aliasing? I can do that – see my update.

Answer (score 2):

I would solve this one of two ways.

First, by using [`List::Utils`](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html)'s `pairmap`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw(pairmap);

my @x = (1 .. 4);

my @result = pairmap {$a, $b**2} @x;

print "@result\n";
```

Or more simply, by just using the indexes:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @x = (1 .. 4);

my @result = map {$_ % 2 ? $x[$_] ** 2 : $x[$_]} (0..$#x);

print "@result\n";
```

However, if you really wanted a new sub, I'd just setup a flip-flop:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub map_even(&@) {
    my $block = shift;
    my $even = 1;
    map {($even ^= 1) ? $block->() : $_} @_;
}
print join " ", map_even {$_*$_} 1,2,3,4;
```

All output:

```
1 4 3 16
```

Comment: @mpapec I was looking for `pairmap`, but couldn't find it.  That's one problem with having about 3 different list utilities.  Gunna switch out my `natatime` suggestion for that.

Comment: btw, I can't really remember last time when someone did such 30 day statistic http://stackoverflow.com/tags/perl/topusers :)

Comment: Thanks @mpapec.  After 10 years as the solo tech person in non-profit companies, I've enjoyed getting back into the swing of things by helping others.  Will hopefully have a new job here soon, and then I will take a break.  Until then, I still got some catching up to do with all of you fellow experts ;)

Comment: @mpapec, `pairmap` is in the core in the latest Perl 5.19.x releases, but the versions of List::Util bundled with older Perls are too old to include it. If your Perl is too old to bundle List::Util::pairmap, List::Util is also available on CPAN. The latest version of List::Util will still work on Perl as old as 5.6.x.